# 2 Modals in the same form but 1 button isn't going off

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio, modal-dialog

#### Problem

I'm creating a webshop and I want to use two different modals in one form in my masterpage, one modal is to create accounts and the other modal is to log users in.

The first modal works perfect, you can open the modal with the button, the buttons inside the modal also work perfect (e.g., register and close buttons). But the other modal (log in) doesn't work, you can open the modal and close the modal, but you can't log in. So the button log in inside the modal "log in" doesn't work, I have some C# code behind that button, but it never activated the code because the button doesn't go off. I put a breakpoint just after the `BtnLogin_click`, but even the breakpoint doesn't go off. The thing is if I put the second modal (register) in comment, the login modal works again or there must be something wrong in form right? Any tips or advice?

#### Attempt

The things I tried are:

> Looked at the properties of the button, then event, and it said it's onclick with the correct name. Tried to create a new button, and a new onclick event.

#### HTML

The 2 buttons to open the modals

```
<input type = "button" id="btnShowLogin" class="btn btn-primary" value = "Login" />
<input type = "button" id="btnShowRegister" class="btn btn-primary" value = "Registreer" />
```

#### Modal 1 Login (not working)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalTitle"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalTitle">
                    Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="txtUsername">
                    Username</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username"
                     />
                <br />
                <label for="txtPassword">
                    Password</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter Password"  />
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRememberMe" Text="Remember Me" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div id="dvMessage" runat="server" visible="false" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Error!</strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">        
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" runat="server" OnClick="ValidateUser" CssClass="btn btn-default" Visible="true" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Modal 2 register (working)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="RegisterModal" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Registreer"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="Registreer">
                    Registreer</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                                <label for="TxtVnaam">
                    Voornaam</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtVnaam" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Voornaam"
                     />
                 <label for="Txtnaam">
                    Achternaam
                 </label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Txtnaam" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Achternaam"
                     />
                 <br />
                 <label for="TxtNick">
                    Username</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtNick" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username"
                     />      
                  <label for="txtEmail">
                    Email</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email"
                     />
                 <br />
                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Required" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Invalid email address." />      
                 <label for="txtWW">
                    Wachtwoord</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtWW" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Wachtwoord"
                     />
                 <label for="bevestig">
                    Bevestig Wachtwoord</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="bevestig" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Wachtwoord"
                     /><asp:CompareValidator ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match." ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="txtWW"
                ControlToValidate="bevestig" runat="server" />
                 <label for="TxtGemeente">
                    Gemeente</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtGemeente" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Gemeente"
                     />
                      <label for="TxtPC">
                    Postcode</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPC" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Postcode"
                     />
                 <br />
                    <label for="TxtAdres">
                    Adres</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAdres" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter adres"
                     />
                 <br />
                  <label for="TxtTel">
                    Telefoonnummer</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTel" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Telefoonnummer"
                     />
    <label for="TxtRek">
                    Rekeningnummer</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtRek" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter rekeningnummer"
                     />
                 <br />                                                                     
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Registreer" runat="server" OnClick="RegisterUser" Class="btn btn-primary" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnShowLogin").click(function () {
            $('#LoginModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#btnShowRegister").click(function () {
            $('#RegisterModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I expect that the button login inside the modal login will active so it can use the code I put behind it and validate the user.

Comment: Both modals working fine, need more clarification to resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I know that the modals are working fine , but the button "btnLogin" inside the modal  "Loginmodal" doesn't work . If you click on it nothing happens. It doesn't even go to the code behind that I wrote in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set ValidationGroup attribute for RequiredFieldValidator for registering .
for example :

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="register" ErrorMessage="Required" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
            ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server" />
```

when use asp validators you should set ValidationGroup attribute because in your case you have 2 submit buttons and when you click on log in button validator of registration  show the message in hidden modal and form will not submit.